# Downloading a file from a webserver error (C++)

Tags: c++

As the title says, I want to download a file from a webserver (eg. localhost/file.txt), but there is a problem. When I use "URLDownloadToFileW", "URLDownloadToFile" and "URLDownloadToFileA", the function return true, but the file doesn't download.

Here is the function that downloads the file:

```
void MyFunction() {
    const char* url_to_download = "localhost/file.txt";
    const char* file_dest = "C:\\fileDownloaded.txt";

    if (S_OK != URLDownloadToFile(NULL, url_to_download, file_dest, 0, NULL)) {
        system("cls");
        std::cout << "Failed to get dll!";
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Again, my problem is that the file doesn't download (i can't find the file where I told the URLDownload function to save), but URLDownloadToFile function return true (it returns S_OK but  for the sake of this post, let's say that it returns true)

Thanks!

Comment: From the docs: "URLDownloadToFile returns S_OK even if the file cannot be created and the download is canceled." and "S_OK: The download **started** successfully.". And "For best control over the download and its progress, an IBindStatusCallback interface is recommended."

Comment: Is `"localhost/file.txt"` a valid URL? There is no scheme in there. Just asking, I don't know.

Comment: @john I gave an example, the url i am downloading from is a discord attachment (https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/.../Lunatic.dll)

Comment: @Mat Thanks for the reply but I don't heard about IBindStatusCallback. Can you give me a documentation on the subject please? Thanks!

Comment: Type the function name in google and you'll reach the MSDN docs immediately, with lots of links.

Comment: Sorry, but answers will always be based on the code posted, how could it be any different.